# Display tabs using angular 5?

Tags: angular5

I am developing a custom tabbed component as mentioned in this blog: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/

I have a another component where I insert the tabs by lopping:
This is withing ListComponent.html:

```
<div>
   <tabs *ngFor="let tab of tabNames">
     <tab tabTitle="{{tab}}">testing {{tab}}</tab>
   </tabs>
 </div>
```

The "tabNames" array is defined in the Listcomponent:

> export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
>
> tabs: string[];
>
> constructor() { }
>
> ```
>   getTabs(): Observable<string[]>     {
>       var tabNames: string[] = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
>       return Observable.of(tabNames);     }
>
>
>       ngOnInit()      {
>
>
>
> this.getTabs().subscribe(data => {    
>     this.tabs = data;
>
>       },
>     error => {
>       console.log("ngOnInit: Error while fetching, " + error);
>   })
>
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Though the array has 3 tab names, nothing gets displayed in UI.
Can anyone help me with solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you seem to be creating multiple `tabs` rather than `tab` component. Try moving the `*ngFor` loop to the `tab` component.

```
<div>
   <tabs>
     <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabNames" tabTitle="{{tab}}">testing {{tab}}</tab>
   </tabs>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

So to further explain how this plunker works: https://plnkr.co/edit/tPhZLwrNRSFcDtQk2ifU?p=preview

Rather than using a `QueryList` to find the Content in the DOM, we let the `Tab` do the work. So, running the `*ngFor` loop on the `<tab>` element within the `<tabs>` creates all the tabs and uses the `Tab`'s constructor to add itself to the `Tabs` parent.

**EDIT 2**

It would appear that plunker is down right now, so here is a breakdown of what the typescript code would look like with the above html:

**Tabs.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs'
})

public class Tabs {
    private _tabs: Tab[] = [];

    public addTab(tab: Tab) {
        if (this._tabs.length === 0) {
            tab.isActive = true;
        }
        this._tabs.push(tab);
    }

    public switchTab(tab: Tab) {
        for (let t of this._tabs) {
            t.isActive = false;
        }

        tab.isActive = true;
    }
}
```

**Tab.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'tab'
})

public class Tab {
    public isActive: boolean;
    @Input('tabname') public tabName: string;

    //Since Tabs is the container element, we can pass reference to the constructor
    constructor(tabs: Tabs) {
        tabs.addTab(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the change you mentioned in my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MK5RgIBuxe9jhRTCeAYq?p=preview. If you see the console, there is an error thrown: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'" How to solve this?

Comment: So from the look of your plnker you almost had it, I've updated it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tPhZLwrNRSFcDtQk2ifU?p=preview . What was happening was a race condition between your querylists foreach loop and the activeTabs filter.

Comment: All these above mentions links are not working...Can some provide the updated plnkr url that is in working form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @HassanRaza, it looks like plunker is down / not working. I've edited my answer with some code, bare in mind it might be different from whats on plunker.